# What is the local structure of a general Artin stack?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, differentiable-stacks

Let $X$ be an Artin stack over the complex numbers.  What can one say about the local structure of $X$, i.e. what is the simplest class of stacks by which were can always find a cover of $X$ by open substacks in this class?  For example, does $X$ always have a cover by open substacks of the form $U/G$ where $G$ is an algebraic group acting on a scheme or complex analytic space $U$?  I actually suspect that this is false, and that a counterexample is given by the moduli stack of nodal genus zero curves (I don't see how to construct such a neighborhood around $\mathbb CP^1\vee\mathbb CP^1$).  If it is indeed false, what is the best one can say?  I am very willing to **pass to the analytification** of $X$ if this helps get a stronger local structure result.

A related question: [Stacks as local quotients or via atlases](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346149/stacks-as-local-quotients-or-via-atlases)

Comment: What do you mean by the "coarse space"?

Comment: @Angelo: Thank you, I've rephrased the question to avoid that notion.

Comment: A DM stack has a coarse space, but it's still an algebraic space, and  [algebraic spaces can be pathological](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Z0).

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question, but if your stack is etale locally a quotient stack then surely it is also locally a quotient stack for the analytic topology? Since an etale cover can be refined to an analytic open cover.

Comment: @DanPetersen: By Artin stack I just mean it has a smooth atlas (plus some condition in the diagonal).  It's definitely not assumed *a priori* to be etale locally a quotient stack.

Comment: Sure, I get that you don't want to assume this a priori. I mean rather: why isn't your question answered by the Alper-Hall-Rydh structure theorem discussed in the question you linked to?

Comment: @DanPetersen The assumption in that result that the stabilizer groups are linearly reductive is too restrictive for the setting I'm interested in.  For example, it does not hold for the point $\mathbb CP^1\vee\mathbb CP^1$ in the moduli stack of nodal curves.

Comment: A stack which is the quotient by a group $G$ has inertia all subgroups of $G$. A finite dimensional algebraic group cannot contain infinitely many abelian varieties (up to isogeny?). Thus the moduli of (unmarked) genus 1 curves, which has inertia all elliptic curves is not locally a quotient stack. But I think that a finite dimesional family of unipotent groups can be embedded in a single linear group.

Answer (score 4):

The stack of curves of genus 0 with at most one node is a quotient stack (see *The integral Chow ring of the stack of at most 1-nodal rational curves*, but Edidin and Fulghesu), so you are fine in this case.

On the other hand, Andrew Kresch proved that the stack of nodal curves of genus 0 with at most two nodes is not a quotient stack (*Flattening stratification and the stack of partial stabilizations of prestable curves*). Given that this stack has only three points, this should gives a counterexample.